# return collection of same parameter as input collection parameter

Tags: java, generics

Say I have the following setup:

```
abstract class AbstractBaseClass {

    // Some common attributes

    AbstractBaseClass() { }

    AbstractBaseClass(AbstractBaseClass orig) {
        // Copy ctor impl
    }

    protected abstract AbstractBaseClass clone();
}

class DerivedClassA extends AbstractBaseClass {

    // Some specialized attributes

    DerivedClassA() { }

    DerivedClassA(DerivedClassA orig) {
        super(orig);
        // Copy ctor impl
    }

    List<DerivedClassB> subObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    protected DerivedClassA clone() {
        return new DerivedClassA(this);
    }

}

class DerivedClassB extends AbstractBaseClass {

    // Some specialized attributes

    DerivedClassB() { }

    DerivedClassB(DerivedClassB orig) {
        super(orig);
        // Copy ctor impl
    }

    List<DerivedClassC> subObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    protected DerivedClassB clone() {
        return new DerivedClassB(this);
    }

}

// DerivedClassC implemented the same way
```

Now I'd like to implement a generic method in my abstract base class which
clones a given list of subjects contained in one of the derived classes:

```
abstract class AbstractBaseClass {

    // Other stuff, see above

    // Doesn't work because of type issues
    protected <T> List<T> cloneList(List<? extends AbstractBaseClass> origList) {
        if (origList == null) return null;

        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (AbstractBaseClass i: origList) {
            result.add(i.clone());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now I want to call this method as follows:

```
class DerivedClassA extends AbstractBaseClass {

    // Other stuff

    List<DerivedClassB> subObjects;

    DerivedClassA(DerivedClassA orig) {
        super(orig);
        // Copy ctor impl
        subObjects = cloneList(orig.subObjects);
    }        

}
```

Now what I'd expect is that the implementation of `cloneList(...)` in `AbstractBaseClass` returns a list that has the same type as the argument list, so I can store them in my derived classes. How would I go about that?

What I've found out so far is that I can implement `cloneList(...)` like so:

```
protected List<AbstractBaseClass> cloneList(List<? extends AbstractBaseClass> origList) {
    // null check...

    List<AbstractBaseClass> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (AbstractBaseClass i: origList) {
        result.add(i.clone());
    }

    return result;
}
```

and then use casts in my derived classes:

```
DerivedClassA(DerivedClassA orig) {
    super(orig);
    // Copy ctor impl
    List<AbstractBaseClass> tmp = cloneList(orig.subObjects);
    for (DerivedClassA i: tmp) {
        subObjects.add( (DerivedClassA) i );
    }
}
```

But this isn't really satisfying to me, since I'd like to have one generic implementation that doesn't rely on casting after getting my cloned collection of objects of type `AbstractBaseClass`

Comment: as you want a 'generic' implementation, generics might we worth a look

Comment: check this page: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: *be aware* "The clone facility suffers from serious design flaws" http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4220218

Comment: The problem is that Object#clone returns an Object so you cannot make it generic, you always have to cast at some point.

Comment: I'm not calling Object.clone(), I have implemented my own clone() function.
Stultuske: I have looked at generics, I just don't understand how I can get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the following lines:

```
abstract class AbstractBaseClass<T extends AbstractBaseClass<T>>
```

and

```
protected List<T> cloneList(List<T> origList) {
    if (origList == null)
        return null;

    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T i : origList) {
        result.add(i.clone());
    }

    return result;
}
```

and the derived class

```
class DerivedClassA extends AbstractBaseClass<DerivedClassA>
```

and

```
DerivedClassA(DerivedClassA orig) {
    super(orig);

    List<DerivedClassA> clonedList = cloneList(orig.subObjects);
    subObjects.addAll(clonedList);
}
```

In the end you do not need to cast anything.